# ActiveRecordでリレーションを組んだカラムの指定方法

Tags: ruby, rails-activerecord

`Post`

- id
- title
- body

`Comment`

- id
- body
- post_id

この2つをリレーションで組んだ時、データを取得する際のカラムの指定の仕方がわかりません。

たとえば、`Post.id`,`Post.title`,`Comment.id`,`Comment.body`を取得したい場合はどのように`select()`を書けば良いのでしょうか?

Comment: 参照の仕方ではなく取得の仕方です

Comment: 質問内容と直接関係ないコメントですが: 質問はあとから[edit]して、補足情報を追加したり、書き直したりできます。(質問本文の左下に灰色の「編集」リンクがあると思います。) すると、サイトトップの質問一覧で一番上に表示されるので、更新した内容で質問に注目を集めることができます。質問の意図がうまく伝わらなかった時には、再度色んな人に見てもらえるので便利です。

Answer (score 2):

PostクラスとCommentクラスがこんなふうに定義されてるとします。

```
class Post
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment
  belongs_to :post
end
```

特定のPost1件と、それにひもづくCommentの一覧を表示する場合はこんなふうになります。

```
class PostController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

こちらはViewです。(`views/posts/show.html.erb`)

```
Title: <%= @post.title %>
Body: <%= @post.body %>
Comments:
<ul>
<% @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
<li><%= comment.body %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

複数のPostと、それぞれのPostに紐付くCommentの一覧を取得するのであれば、このようになるはずです。

```
posts = Post.all # または Post.where(title: '今日のできごと') など
posts.each do |post|
  id = post.id
  title = post.title
  body = post.body
  post.comments.each do |comment|
    comment_id = comment.id
    comment_body = comment.body
    post_id = comment.post_id
  end
end
```

ちなみに、関連を持つモデルのデータの作成方法は昔Qiitaで詳しく説明したので、そちらも良かったら参考にしてみてください。

[[初心者向け] Railsで関連するデータ(親子関係)を保存する方法あれこれ](http://qiita.com/jnchito/items/7f41ff3df900909952db)

Answer (score 1):

すでにリレーションをくんだ前提(has_many, belongs_toアソシエーションの記載済み)で話をします。
リレーションに関しては説明がドットインストールにもありますので参考にしてみてください。
(http://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_rails_v2)

その場合なら、例えばidが１のポストに対するのコメントをとりたいのであれば、

```
@post = Post.where(id = 1)
@post.id //ここにpostのIDが入っています。
@post.title //ここにpostのIDが入っています。
@post.Comment.id //ここにコメントのIDが入っています。
@post.Comment.body //ここにコメントのbodyが入っています。
```

のようにすれば、必要なものが取得できるかと思います。

Comment: > @post = Post.where(id = 1)
この時点で必要なものを指定したいのです。
たとえば`Post.select('id').all`のように

Answer (score 1):

以下の様なことでしょうか？

```
@posts = Post.joins(:comments)
             .select('posts.id, comments.id as cid, posts.body, comments.body as cbody')
```

これのto_sql は以下になります(改行は私が入れました)。

```sql
SELECT posts.id, comments.id as cid, posts.body, comments.body as cbody 
  FROM "posts" INNER JOIN 
       "comments" ON "comments"."post_id" = "posts"."id"
```

モデルは以下のようになっています。

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Answer (score 0):

「参照の仕方ではなく取得の仕方です」ということですから。
おそらくSELECT文の時点で絞り込みたいのだと思います。

しかし「Post.id,Post.title,Comment.id,Comment.body」の4つを取得した時に、
取得したインスタンスに対しての .id が Post.idを示すのかComment.idを示すのか判断できません。

一般的には、flied onionさんのように、select('posts.id as ...')としますが。
arel_tableを使うと自由度は高まります。

```
p1 = Post.arel_table['id']
p2 = Post.arel_table['title']
c1 = Comment.arel_table['id'].as('comment_id')
c2 = Comment.arel_table['body']
posts = Post.joins(:comment).select(p1, p2, c1, c2)
posts.first.body # 行データに収まっているのでincludes不要
```

もちろん Post.arel_table['*']もOKです。

私自身arel_tableを頻繁に使わないので希望に添えているかどうかとか。
もっと綺麗な使い方があるんじゃないかとか多少心配がありますが。
テーブル名を文字列で渡して、ピリオドやクォートが手間だと思い始めたら
arel_tableを使うことを検討してください。

※ activerecord-sqlserver-adapterの環境下で問題ないことは確認しました。